# integer type split into two columns

Tags: r, split

I've column with two alpha numeric characters separated by '->' I'm trying to split them into columns.

---

Df:

```
 column e 
1. asd1->ref2
2. fde4 ->fre4
3. dfgt-fgr ->frt5
4. ftr5 -> lkh-oiut
5. rey6->usre-lynng->usre-lkiujh->kiuj-bunny
6. dge1->fgt4->okiuj-dfet
```

Desired output

```
  col 1    col 2
1. asd1     ref2
2. fde4     fre4
3.          frt5
4. ftr5 
5. rey6
6. dge1     fgt4
```

I tried using `out <- strsplit(as.character(Df$column e),'_->_')` with no output and used `str_extract(m1$column e,"(?<=\\[)[[:alnum:]]")->m1$column f`, also strsplit(as.character(Df$column e),' -> 'fixed=T)[[1]][[1]] but not getting the desired output.

The column if of integer type and all are capital letters(I'm not sure if this is imp.)

Comment: I think it should be noted that `Df$column e` will probably confuse things. you may need to either remove the space from that column name (`Df$columne`), or quote the column name (`Df$'column e'`).

Comment: right, my column's actual name is Df$column.e

Comment: @ycw, noted. in the last question I was getting the correct output but it was copying the other columns present in the data frame and paste it beside the original one.

Comment: @ycw, question is same, but found two new solutions resolving my issue. I'll make sure not to repeat question. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
    separate(columne, into = c('col1', 'col2'), sep = "->", extra = 'drop') %>% 
    mutate_all(funs(replace(., str_detect(., '-'), "")))
#   col1 col2
#1  asd1 ref2
#2 fde4  fre4
#3       frt5
#4 ftr5      
#5  rey6     
#6  dge1 fgt4
```

Comment: this works, thanks.
I was trying to add the columns to my original data frame using `df1 %>% 
    separate(columne, into = c('col1', 'col2'), sep = "->", extra = 'drop') %>% 
    mutate_all(funs(replace(., str_detect(., '-'), ""))) ->Df$lk` , It is duplicating the data frame and adding it at the end, how can I just add the two columns, col1 and col2 to my original data frame without repeating any other columns

Comment: @kishore the `separate` argument `remove = FALSE` can be used if we need to restore the original column. i.e. `df1 %>% separate(columne, into = c('col1', 'col2'), sep = "->", extra = 'drop', remove = FALSE) %>% mutate_at(vars(matches("col\\d+")), funs(replace(., `

Answer (score 1):

A `base` R solution as well, though a fair bit less concise than @akrun's `tidyverse` one:

```
# split as appropriate
out <- strsplit( as.character( Df$column.e ), '->' )

out <- lapply( out, function(x) {

    # I assume you don't want the white space
    y <- trimws( x )

    # take the first two "columns"
    y <- y[1:2]

    # remove any items containing a hyphen
    y[ grepl( "-", y ) ] <- ""
    y
    }
)

# then bind it all rowwise
out <- do.call( rbind, out )
data.frame( out )

    X1   X2
1 asd1 ref2
2 fde4 fre4
3      frt5
4 ftr5     
5 rey6     
6 dge1 fgt4
```

Comment: yes this works great. thank you :).  Can we name the columns inside this function?

Comment: Yes, several ways to do that. Probably easiest just to assign them at the end with `names(df)<-c("col1","col2")`